# Get property name with TryValidateObject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to validate a model in my MVC 5 project. I have created a method which validates a model based on its ValidationAttributes and returns a list of string of error messages

```
public static ModelStateDictionary ValidateModelWithPropertyNames<T>(this T obj, List<string> excludeProperties = null)
{
    var ret = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    var message = string.Empty;
    var propertyName = string.Empty;
    ModelStateDictionary dic = new ModelStateDictionary();
    var context = new ValidationContext(obj, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, context, results, true);
    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        message = item.ToString();
        propertyName = item.MemberNames.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
        if (excludeProperties != null && excludeProperties.Any(u => u == propertyName))
            continue;

        dic.AddModelError(propertyName, message);
    }
    return dic;
}
```

I am trying to get the property name by using

```
propertyName = item.MemberNames.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

but the MemberNames is always empty. Is there a way I can get the property name with the validation issue? For example if i have a property defined like this

```
[Required]
[ExtraInfo(ColumnName = "Description_English_Column")]
[Display(Name = "English Description")]
public string DescriptionEN { get; set; }
```

If its null or empty the method will return a message like

> "The English Description field is required".

So far so good but I also need to know the property's name in order to retreive the ExtraInfo custom Attribute value.

Comment: Can we take a look inside what Validator does?

Comment: You mean the TryValidateObject?

Comment: Yes. You questioned about why the MemberNames was invalid but you didn't show how it was assigned.

Comment: TryValidateObject is part of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations library